# How to Find IMEI Number from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sim

The Thinkpad X1 Carbon has built-in 4G which takes a Micro-SIM card. After getting a Micro-SIM, I was told to call in to activate it. The network operator though requires an IMEI number and refuses to make the Micro-SIM active without it.

There is no IMEI number anywhere on my laptop, its box or the documentation. How can I query Windows 7 to return IMEI. Tried to look in the Device Manager and the output from IPCONFIG but I cannot find it. I have the MAC addresses which were also on the box but no IMEI.

Comment: I would contact Lenovo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of your drivers are installed run from CMD as admin:

> netsh mbn show interface

Device ID is the IMEI

Alternatively you can use either the software that came with lenovo - I think the earlier version was called access connections or use some of the 3rd party software pacakges avalaible [- like this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWxgwjid8oI)

Comment: Not working. All drivers are installed and I updated all from Lenovo's System update. First it gave an *wwansvc service not running* error, so I started it manually. Not the command says *There is no Broadband interface*. Could there be a catch-22 and this not work unless connected? Or is there anything to do to activate the driver first? Access Connections does not show anything and has the Broadband option greyed out.

Comment: @Itai I am experiencing the same problem.  I've now spent more than 1 hour on the phone with Lenovo, but they don't know what to do either.

Answer (score 0):

Some models of Lenovo laptops have a sim card slot but do NOT have an internal card which interfaces the sim to the motherboard.  In this case you will get an error saying **There is no Broadband interface** when you try to show the IMEI without the card.

Specifically the Lenovo X1 Carbon 5th Gen has the sim card slot but no internal network card for the sim.  However, the Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th Gen DOES have an internal sim card.  Make sure you get the right laptop!